# Windows command prompt: Using a variable set in the same line of a one-liner

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax, windows-7, cmd

Okay, I learned that one can use `&` or `&&` to combine multiple commands into a single line, but it seems that variables that are `set` aren't actually available for interpolation in the same line:

```
C:\Users\Andrew>set foo=hello, world!&& echo %foo%
%foo%

C:\Users\Andrew>echo %foo%
hello, world!
```

**Why can't I make this work, and is there any way to make it work in a single line?**

The reason I need a one-liner is that an external program I'm working with accepts a single command as a pre-run hook, and, of course, I need to run multiple commands.

---

#### Preemptive Defenses

1. **"`hello, world!` should be surrounded in double-quotes!"** Actually, doing so seems to store literal double-quotes in the variable, which I do not want, *e.g.*

   ```
   C:\Users\Andrew>set bar="hello, world!"&& echo %bar%
   %bar%

   C:\Users\Andrew>echo %bar%
   "hello, world!"
   ```
2. **"There should be a space before the `&&`!"** Actually, doing so seems to store a trailing space in the variable, which I do not want, *e.g.*

   ```
   C:\Users\Andrew>set bar="hello, world!"&& echo %bar%
   %bar%

   C:\Users\Andrew>echo %bar%
   "hello, world!"
   ```
3. **"Both!"** >:(

   ```
   C:\Users\Andrew>set mu="hello, world!" && echo %mu%
   %mu%

   C:\Users\Andrew>echo (%mu%)
   ("hello, world!" )
   ```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it in the same line, but I would recommend to use a batch file like *preHook.bat*.

As one liner

```
set "mu=hello, world!" && call echo %^mu%
```

At first you can see that the quotes are different than yours.

---

Here's why:

```
set test1="quotes"
set "test2=no quotes" with comment
```

In the first test, the quotes will be part of the `test1` variable, as well as all characters after the last quote.

In the second test, it uses the extended syntax of the `SET` command.
So the content will be `no quotes`, as only the content to the last quote is used; the rest will be dropped.

To echo the variable content, I use `call echo %^mu%`, as percent expansion will expand it when the line is parsed, before any of the commands are executed.

But the `call` command will be executed later, and it restarts the parser, which, when used at the command line, uses different expansion rules than the batch parser: an empty variable (in this case, `%^mu%`, in the first time) stays unchanged in the line; but, in the next parser phase, the `^` caret will be removed.

In your case, `call echo %mu%` would also work, but only when `mu` is always empty. The caret variant also works when `mu` has content before the line is executed.

More about the parser at [SO: How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115)
And about variable expansion at [SO: Variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/463115)

Comment: Perfect! Can you explain what the `%^mu%` is doing? (I don't know how to search for it.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Hope my explanation is understandable

Comment: Great explanation. I didn't realize `set` had this alternative syntax, and also that's a really clever trick, the vanishing caret. Thanks so much! (And yes, I considered putting everything in at `bat` file but for... let's say, psychological/logistical reasons, a one-liner would be much-preferred. It's the difference between, _"Okay, everyone, just copy/paste this line into your window, and voila!,"_ and _"Everyone download this file, put it somewhere in your `$PATH`,"_ etc.)

Comment: @jeb If only your English grammar was as good as your batch grammar rofl... I edited your answer to make it a lot more readable, but I'm not quite sure I understand the `%^mu%` part. I **think** what you're saying is that you use `^` to keep the first phase from evaluating `%mu%` prematurely, and you use `call` to have it parse the echo command a second time, after the caret is removed but also after the set command has been flushed through. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: @andrew Thanks for improving my answer. I learn many things from the corrections. And yes, you got it right.

Comment: You saved my life

Comment: The caret trick doesn't work in scripts, but you can do this instead: `set "mu=hello, world!" && call echo %%mu%%` (Again, scripts only.)

Answer (score 8):

Though I accepted @jeb's answer, ultimately I had to go another route, because I needed to pipe the output of my command, and doing so on `call` led to mangled results. Indeed, the documentation for `call` itself remarks,

> Do not use pipes and redirection symbols with **call**.

Instead, reminded by @Blorgbeard of `cmd`'s `/v` option (and I believe that should be lowercase, not uppercase), I realized I could simply start a subprocess:

```
C:\Users\Andrew>cmd /v /c "set foo=hello, world!&& echo !foo!"
hello, world!
```

(For some reason, `/v` must appear before `/c`.) Within the quotes, I was able pipe my output to other utilities. One tip for those taking this path: If you find yourself needing to use quotes *within* those quotes, I suggest avoiding them altogether and trying character codes, *e.g.* `\x20` for space, `\x22` for double quotes, and so on.

For example, this was the eventual solution to my problem (**warning: may cause eyes to bleed**):

```
C:\Users\Andrew>cmd /v /c "set source=C:\source& set target=C:\target& set archive=C:\archive& robocopy.exe !source! !target! /l /e /zb /xx /xl /fp /ns /nc /ndl /np /njh /njs | sed -e s/^^[\t\x20]\+// | sed -e /^^$/d | sed -e s/^!source:\=\\!// | sed -e s/.*/xcopy\x20\/Fvikrhyz\x20\x22!source:\=\\!^&\x22\x20\x22!archive:\=\\!^&\x22/"
```

Comment: _>>> For some reason, /v must appear before /c_ that is because anything specified after /c is argument to /c itself and /v is argument for cmd.exe thus needs to be put before /c

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
cmd.exe /v /c "set foo=hello, world & echo !foo!"
```

The `/v` argument enables [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). This allows you to access variables' values at *execution* time rather than at *parse* time (the default). You do this by writing `!foo!` instead of `%foo%` (with this `/v` option turned on).

Instead of passing `/v`, you can also turn delayed variable expansion on permanently via the registry, which obviously affects the entire system:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"DelayedExpansion"= (REG_DWORD)
1=enabled 0=disabled (default)
```

Comment: Thanks, this led me to another solution, which I'll post shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get an IF command to work with either *call* or *cmd /v /c* so I would like to offer another option for those who may need it:
use FOR /F to declare and use a variable within a single command.
For example:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('echo 123') DO (IF %i==123 echo done)
```

The %i is the variable that is set with the result of the IN command, which in this example is 'echo 123'.

For values with single quotes or spaces, use the "usebackq tokens=*" flag to put the command in backquotes:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i IN (`echo "hello, ' ' world!"`) DO (IF %i=="hello, ' ' world!" echo done)
```