# Create new directory and navigate into it (Windows CMD)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I'm working on a Windows machine using cmd and I want to create a new diretory and navigate into it in one command. Under Unix you can do something like the following:

```
mkdir new_dir && cd $_
```

How can I achieve that under Windows?

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: `md new_dir & cd new_dir`

Comment: Exactly the same way.     `&    seperates commands on a line.`
    
    `&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.`
    
    `||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's 
    errorlevel is NOT 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it's not possible to pipe the previous argument? So I don't have to explicitly write the directory name again. Cause under Unix I can do the exact same thing you wrote, but I can also use the argument from the previous command using $_. And I'm searching for a similar solution.

Comment: `cmd` has no such functionality.

Comment: `doskey cd=md $1 $T cd $1` then `cd dog`. See `Doskey /?`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using Windows Powershell (you can simply execute `powershell` in command prompt to enter an instance of the Powershell shell), this is the closest way to do what you are asking.

```
echo new_dir | %{mkdir $_; cd $_}
```

Adapted from [simonwo's xargs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428950/5652697).

---

However, if for certain reasons you are unable to use Powershell, then this is a method to achieve *very similar* behavior. The issue being simply that you are now using variables instead of redirecting output.

```
SET "d=new_dir" && call mkdir %^d% && call cd %^d%
```

Adapted from [jeb's oneliner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23421825/5652697).

---

Similarly, for a slightly more readable input string and portable method (due to the limitations of `call`) than the above, you can use the following. However, note that you will be moved into a new separate instance of the command line shell.

```
cmd /v /k "set d=new_dir && mkdir !d! && cd !d!"
```

The `/v` argument enables [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), and the `/k` argument carries out the command by the string but remains without terminating.

Adapted from [Blogbeard's oneliner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420433/5652697).

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. I'm bonded with the CMD. I marked your question as most helpful not only because it's the only one, but I think it'll help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Id don´t know how to create, but to navigate use `pushd C:\Path`