# cmd.exe /C unable to run the command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm running below command which is working successfully if I run it manually via command prompt

```bat
SET filename=testfile_26032021.txt && SET newfilename=%filename:~9,8% && copy C:\test\updatedtestfile_%newfilename%.txt C:\test\updatedtestfile_%newfilename%.txt.temp
```

But when I run this through an external call I get an error

```bat
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here's the command I'm running

```bat
cmd.exe /C SET filename=testfile_26032021.txt && SET newfilename=%filename:~9,8% && copy C:\test\updatedtestfile_%newfilename%.txt C:\test\updatedtestfile_%newfilename%.txt.temp
```

I caught the error by changing the flag from /C to /K.

Any idea what is wrong with this command?

Comment: Why not using a batch file instead of a complex one liner?

Comment: The environment I'm working on doesn't allow me to create script or any file for that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do like this `SET filename=testfile_26032021.txt && SET newfilename=%filename:~9,8%` because `%filename%` is expanded at parsing time where it's not available yet. You must [enable delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and tell cmd to expand the command later with `!variable_name!`. Besides `&&` ends the previous command so your whole thing is parsed as 3 commands:

```bat
cmd.exe /C SET filename=testfile_26032021.txt
SET newfilename=%filename:~9,8%
copy C:\test\updatedtestfile_%newfilename%.txt C:\test\updatedtestfile_%newfilename%.txt.temp
```

So you must quote the command like this

```bat
cmd.exe /V:on /C "SET "filename=testfile_26032021.txt" && SET "newfilename=!filename:~9,8!" && copy C:\test\updatedtestfile_!newfilename!.txt C:\test\updatedtestfile_!newfilename!.txt.temp"
```

or

```bat
cmd.exe /C "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && SET filename=testfile_26032021.txt && SET newfilename=!filename:~9,8! && copy C:\test\updatedtestfile_!newfilename!.txt C:\test\updatedtestfile_!newfilename!.txt.temp"
```

See also

- [Windows command prompt: Using a variable set in the same line of a one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23420340/995714)
- [How set a variable and then use it in the same line in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26251171/995714)
- [Setting and using variable within same command line in Windows cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/q/223104/241386)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to run both commands and it still fails with `The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: The last sample can't work, because `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` doesn't work in command line context. The second sample needs some quotes around the `set` commands (I already edited the answer for that)

Comment: I don't have an option of calling a batch script in my solution so I'm unfortunately stuck with one-liners call. That said, the updated command works but ONLY when I call it inside a command prompt. If I go to run box and type the command or call it from my program then I'm getting the same error `The system cannot find the file specified` any idea why?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, not sure why cmd is behaving it this way, when I ran the same command on a different VM it worked, then I restarted my machine and ran the same command again and sure enough, it works.